# Sharepoint downloads aspx file instead of rendering it

Tags: sharepoint-online, aspx

I have uploaded some ASPX files to my SharePoint document library.
When I click on the file, SharePoint downloads the file instead of rendering it in browser.

How can I fix this?

Thank you for assistance.

Answer (score 5):

Upload them into Site Pages library.

If you upload them into Document library this is like document not like page. Use correct library template.

Comment: Well there are folders, js files and PDF files mixed. Document library is not suited for that content. I'm trying to upload a web site which should be rendered from document library.

Comment: But SharePoint doesn't working this way... you should upload aspx pages into Site Pages folder and the rest under SiteAssets and edit references.... Or use simply IIS Site not SharePoint.