# How to add custom aspx page to SharePoint online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, aspx

We have requirement to add customer aspx and its js file to SharePoint online but we dont have SharePoint Designer, if we upload the files to site assets and try to open, it is getting downloaded instead of rendering.

As per this post -
[Sharepoint downloads aspx file instead of rendering it](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/255552/sharepoint-downloads-aspx-file-instead-of-rendering-it)

we tried to upload it to site pages but it is not allowing us to upload the file, it is not allowing us with below error message

[image]

Is there any way to upload the files without SharePoint designer ?
User is only site member, user dont have full control on SharePoint site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need the setting "Allow or prevent custom script" enabled to allow you to upload an ASPX file via the UI. This is noted here:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/types-of-files-that-cannot-be-added-to-a-list-or-library-30be234d-e551-4c2a-8de8-f8546ffbf5b3?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us#ID0EAABAAA=Modern

Details on enabling this setting can be found here:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/sharepoint/allow-or-prevent-custom-script

A global admin or SharePoint admin can enable this setting.

Comment: Thank you for help, it worked for me.